# Did he really have dreams or just hoping?

Tags: word-meaning

> When he had been younger, Harry **had dreamed and dreamed of** some
>   unknown relation coming to take him away, but it had never happened.

Is that his wish when he was awake, or something in his dream? And what's the different between "dream about" and "dream of"? Can I just say "I dream something"? What that suppose mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have to rely on context to know whether "dream" means a sleeping dream or a daydream. Your example most likely refers to daydreams or wishes.

"Dream of" and "dream about" are interchangeable. "I dream something" is not generally idiomatic.